# Error - 'x' and 'y' must have the same length

Tags: r

I am very new to coding and working on a Homework assignment for class.
This is the code and error I am getting:

Code:

```
cor.test(HR_comma_sep$average_monthly_hours , HR_comma_sep$number_project , conf.level = .99)
```

Error:

```
Error in cor.test.default(HR_comma_sep$average_monthly_hours, HR_comma_sep$number_project, : 'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

Any help would be appreciated...keep in mind I am new to this so an answer in layman's terms would help.  If you speak code to me I probably won't understand. :)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You might get better answers by providing your data. Use `dput(HR_comma_sep)`

Comment: Are your column names correct?  R is a case sensitive language.  Another possible item to check is if "average_monthly_hours" or "number_project contain" a NA value